# Participation in (RED) Event AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I just wondered how to activate the (RED) thing for my application. I added a new update to my app, to see if there is a check mark to participate, but it's not. Is it maybe the case that Apple decides which apps are "eligible" for being in that program?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess it's right next to the check boxes for "Feature in App Store", "Install in demo devices in retail stores" and "Demo on-stage at WWDC" :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app promotion

Comment: @Thilo: Oh yeah I found it. Thanks :) (make sure to watch the next WWDC ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Official Press Release](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/11/24Apple-Announces-World-AIDS-Day-2014-Campaign-for-RED-.html):

> From Monday, November 24 through Sunday, December 7, the App Store’s Apps for (RED) campaign will feature 25 fan-favorite apps with exclusive new content. Every time a customer purchases a participating (PRODUCT)RED app or an exclusive In-App Purchase, all proceeds will go to the Global Fund.

It looks like Apple is hand picking the apps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "activation". Apple partnered with a selected set of app developers for the (RED) promotion. There are only 25 apps total that participated in the program.